# Progressive Dinner - couples and singles

Tags: combinatorics

We have a Christmas dinner each year and we change tables for each course (3) Salad, Dinner, Dessert.  This year there are 39 people, 18 couples and 3 singles. No one is supposed to sit with another couple or single person more than once. There are 5 tables of 8. I have worked this out many ways and I keep getting at least 1 single person sitting with others multiple times. It seems impossible. Looking for some help.

Comment: Is it safe to say that a couple must always sit together at a table?

Comment: Yes.  I tried to mix and match the 3 singles but one always ended up at table with someone twice.  I did figure out if I left 2 of the singles as a "couple" then no one sat together more than once. However, my boss hopes we can try and not do that. I found  my only solution was to do 6 tables of 7.  There would always be at least 6 at a table with 1 single or sometimes 2 at a table. I am going to bring her that solution if I can't work out the 5 tables. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Those are some smart alternatives to use as plan B. Lucky for you, combinations are on your side. It is possible! See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, by combining the power of Mathematics and programming I have managed to find an arrangement of 5 tables that will successfully give you what you are looking for. In order to understand the answer, we are going to have to agree on a little bit of notation. The numbers $1-18$ are each going to represent a couple, thus they take up two spots at a table. The numbers $19,20,21$ are going to represent the three single people that you have. In order for you to easily use this, I would suggest following this notation by assigning each couple/guest a number, or else replacing these numbers with the appropriate names.

A row of five matrices is going to represent a single meal, and in that row, each table is going to represent a matrix that has 4 entries. Each entry represents two seats at the table, thus $$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 16 \\ 19 & 20/21 \end{bmatrix}$$
would mean that the third and sixteenth couple are at the table, accompanied by single person $19$ (and an empty seat next to him/her) and single people $20/21$ who have been grouped together for the sake of notation.
Surprisingly, there is more than one possible answer, in fact there are many, they are just hard to find. Here is one solution:
$$
\text{Salad:}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}\;\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 19 \end{bmatrix}\;\begin{bmatrix} 8 & 9 \\ 10 & 11 \end{bmatrix}\;\begin{bmatrix} 12 & 13 \\ 14 & 20/21 \end{bmatrix}\;\begin{bmatrix} 15 & 16 \\ 17 & 18 \end{bmatrix}$$$$\text{Dinner:}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 11 \\ 16 & 19/21 \end{bmatrix}\;\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 2 \\ 13 & 17 \end{bmatrix}\;\begin{bmatrix} 8 & 3 \\ 18 & 20 \end{bmatrix}\;\begin{bmatrix} 12 & 4 \\ 9 & 6 \end{bmatrix}\;\begin{bmatrix} 15 & 10 \\ 14 & 7 \end{bmatrix}$$$$
\text{Dessert:} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 13 \\ 7 & 18 \end{bmatrix}\;\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 4 \\ 11 & 14 \end{bmatrix}\;\begin{bmatrix} 8 & 21 \\ 17 & 6 \end{bmatrix}\;\begin{bmatrix} 12 & 3 \\ 10 & 16 \end{bmatrix}\;\begin{bmatrix} 15 & 2 \\ 9 & 19/20 \end{bmatrix}
$$

For ease and possible convenience to help prove that nobody will end up with the same person twice, I am going to list each number with the corresponding numbers that they will end up dining with in order of each course. The lists are "sorted" in the way that correspond most intuitively to me, by starting in the top-left corner and moving across.

Notice that $1,5,8,12,15$ are all assigned to the "same" table for each event, but this can be changed by simply having each table be randomized. It's likely that at least somebody will end up not moving, but your original goal was just to ensure that nobody dines together more than once.

$1$ dines with $2,3,4 \quad 11,16,19,21 \quad 13,7,18$

$2$ dines with $1,3,4 \quad 5,13,17 \quad 15,9,19,20$

$3$ dines with $1,2,4 \quad 8,18,20 \quad 12,10,16$

$4$ dines with $1,2,3 \quad 12,9,6 \quad 5,11,14$

$5$ dines with $6,7,19 \quad 2,17,13 \quad 4,11,14$

$6$ dines with $5,7,19 \quad 4,12,9 \quad 8,17,21$

$7$ dines with $5,6,19 \quad 15,10,14 \quad 1,13,18$

$8$ dines with $9,10,11 \quad 3,18,20 \quad 21,17,6$

$9$ dines with $8,10,11 \quad 12,4,6 \quad 15,2,19,20$

$10$ dines with $8,9,11 \quad 15,14,7 \quad 12,3,16$

$11$ dines with $8,9,10 \quad 1,16,19,21 \quad 5,4,14$

$12$ dines with $13,14,20,21 \quad 4,9,6 \quad 3,10,16$

$13$ dines with $12,14,20,21 \quad 5,2,17 \quad 1,7,18$

$14$ dines with $12,13,20,21 \quad 15,10,7 \quad 5,4,11$

$15$ dines with $16,17,18 \quad 10,14,7 \quad 2,9,19,20$

$16$ dines with $15,17,18 \quad 1,11,19,21 \quad 12,3,10$

$17$ dines with $15,16,18 \quad 5,2,13 \quad 8,21,6$

$18$ dines with $15,16,17 \quad 8,3,20 \quad 1,13,7$

$19$ dines with $5,6,7 \quad 1,11,16,21 \quad 15,2,9,20$

$20$ dines with $12,13,14,21 \quad 8,3,18 \quad 15,2,9,19$

$21$ dines with $12,13,14,20 \quad 1,11,16,19 \quad 8,17,6$

Now let's discuss how I did it, in case you're still reading this and are interested: I originally did a little bit of guessing, thinking I was clever enough to figure one out on my own, and ended up with a few different results, all that had at least one pair that sat together twice.

I decided that it was very easy to make sure nobody sat together during the first two courses, so I drew it up (the one listed as the solution). The trick was getting them to still be unique for the third course and that's when I turned to Python for assistance.
I wrote up all of the different numbers and who they had already sat with at the end of the first two courses. I then arbitrarily chose $1,5,8,12,15$ to be the 'head' of each table. I created a little function that detected whether or not people had already sat together and then began trying to randomly assign individuals to the tables for the third course. After only a handful of attempts the program returned this answer. As mentioned I was able to find many different results for Dessert, and the results become more numerous as you can modify even one couple in the Salad course which can change the end results.

Happy Holidays, and may you enjoy a party with a unique experience for everybody.

Comment: Hi Mitch, thank you so much!  When I have time, I am going to read in detail how you accomplished this but now I have my seating chart. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help :)